# selectedRow gets cleared whenever fireTableCellUpdated is called

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor, listselectionlistener

I believe this is quite a common problem, when i called the fireTableCellUpdated my selectedRow gets cleared. I tried saving my row by calling this:

```
final int savedRow = mainTable.getSelectedRow();
...
if ( savedRow > 0 ) {
   mainTable.setRowSelectionInterval(savedRow, savedRow);
}
```

It does't work because savedRow always returns -1!

Does anyone know how to prevent my selectedRow from being cleared??

Comment: For better help sooner,post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: something wrong with the code you are not showing ... maybe related to the potentially incorrect (and hidden as well ;-) code [in your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14441125/203657) - If you have a problem, it simply doesn't make sense to plow on without getting to the root of it. To spell it out again: something is **WRONG** with your code, without you showing an SSCCE (as you were asked to do more than once) there is **NO** way to help you. So either do show it or be on your own.

Answer (score 3):

A simple example shows the selection is NOT cleared on `fireTableCellUpdated()` (which is called by `DefaultTableModel#setValueAt()`:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestTable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(3, 3);
                JTable table = new JTable(model);
                table.setRowSelectionInterval(1, 1);

                final Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                    private final Random random = new Random();
                    private int i;

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        model.setValueAt(i++, random.nextInt(3), random.nextInt(3));
                    }
                });
                timer.start();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                        timer.stop();
                    }
                });
                frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Below statement will give **-1** if there is no row selected.

```
final int savedRow = mainTable.getSelectedRow();
```

> when i called the fireTableCellUpdated my selectedRow gets cleared

What is the reason behind calling the `fireXXXMethod`? These methods should be called if their is any change in the table data. But in your case you are not changing data but just saving the data which is in the table. So it is no necessary here.

P.S: For sooner help please post the code which shows the problem.